# How to Fix Discontinuity Issues in Plotly 3D Surface Plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python

[photop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RBqb.jpg)I encountered some discontinuity issues when creating 3D graphics with Python's Plotly module. To address this, I attempted to extend the data from 0 to 175 degrees by repeating the last angle as 180 degrees, but the graph still shows discontinuities. I would greatly appreciate any guidance from the experts on how to resolve this problem.

```
raw data==>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T9Hsmjb0G-PB2oaATsAX_K9NrJwMIXEMBa1N2EXxX4Y/edit#gid=0
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, Button

def draw_3d_radiation_pattern_with_plotly(file_path):
    # reading csv file
    raw_data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    

    theta_degrees = raw_data.iloc[:, 0]  # THETA angle
    phi_degrees = (raw_data.columns[1:].astype(int))  # PHI angle
    e_total_db = (raw_data.iloc[:, 1:].values)  # E Total value in dB
    print(f"phi's angle'{phi_degrees}")
    print(f"theta's angle'{theta_degrees}")
    # degree transfer to radians
    theta_radians =abs(np.radians(theta_degrees)) 
    phi_radians =abs(np.radians(phi_degrees)) 



    e_total_linear = e_total_db
    
   
    max_e_total = np.max(e_total_linear)
    print("matrix max value:", max_e_total)

    e_total_normalized = e_total_linear - np.amin(e_total_linear)
    e_total_normalized /= np.amax(e_total_normalized)
  
    theta_grid, phi_grid = np.meshgrid(theta_radians, phi_radians, indexing='ij')


    r = e_total_normalized*max_e_total  
    x = r * np.sin(theta_grid) * np.cos(phi_grid)
    y = r * np.sin(theta_grid) * np.sin(phi_grid)
    z = r * np.cos(theta_grid)

    # 使用Plotly繪製3D圖形
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(
        x=x, y=y, z=z,
        surfacecolor=e_total_db,  #show dB
        cmin=np.min(e_total_db),  # settin color table min
        cmax=np.max(e_total_db),  # settin color table max
        colorscale='Jet',  # using Jet
    )])

    fig.update_layout(
        title='testing',
        autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            xaxis_title='X',
            yaxis_title='Y',
            zaxis_title='Z',
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=1)
        ),
        width=700, height=700
    )
    

    fig.show()

def open_file_dialog():
    root = Tk()  
    root.withdraw()  
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()  
    if file_path:  
        draw_3d_radiation_pattern_with_plotly(file_path)
    root.destroy()

# GUI part
gui_root = Tk()
gui_root.title("3D Radiation Pattern Visualization with Plotly")
load_button = Button(gui_root, text="Load Excel DATA and Draw", command=open_file_dialog)
load_button.pack(pady=20)
gui_root.mainloop()
```